# commenting out cout statement causes different (and incorrect) output

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have never experienced anything like this. I was using a cout statement to help me debug a small program, and once I was satisfied with my code I commented out the cout. Now, the code no longer works. Below is the code with the cout commented out.

The intent of this program is to test the two hard coded boolean two dimensional arrays for having an odd number of true statements on each row. Thus, the first array should return true and the second array should return false. With the cout statement commented out both instead return false.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <size_t size_y>
bool findEvenDegrees(bool mapArray[][size_y])
{
    bool returnValue;
    for (int x=0; x<size_y; x++)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int y=0; y<size_y; y++)
        {
            result = result + mapArray[x][y];
            //the line below causes the problem
            cout << mapArray[x][y] << "\t" << result << "\t" << x << endl;
        }
        if (result%2 == 1)
        {
            returnValue = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (returnValue== false)
    {
        return returnValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool array1[][6] =
    {
        {false,true,true,false,false,false},
        {true,false,false,true,false,false},
        {true,false,false,true,false,false},
        {false,true,true,false,true,true},
        {false,false,false,true,false,true},
        {false,false,false,true,true,false}
    };
    bool array2[][8] =
    {
        {false,true,true,false,false,false,false,false},
        {true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false},
        {true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false},
        {false,true,true,false,true,false,false,false},
        {false,false,false,true,false,true,true,false},
        {false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true},
        {false,false,false,false,true,false,false,true},
        {false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false}
    };
    bool answer1 = findEvenDegrees(array1);
    bool answer2 = findEvenDegrees(array2);
    if (answer1 == true)
    {
        cout << "Array 1 has a even degree for every switch." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Array 1 has a odd degree for at least one switch." << endl;
    }
    if (answer2 == true)
    {
        cout << "Array 2 has a even degree for every switch.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Array 2 has a odd degree for at least one switch.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Commented out the `cout` part.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=94e5c41fe17a9a5f86815122c813b6a8-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Comment: either `size_y != x || size_y != y`. They don't have same size as you can see in Boolean array in your main.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize `returnValue`. If it happens to start out as `false` it will stay that way and the function will return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

First, I cleaned up your code a little, and arrived at:

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t S>
bool findEvenDegrees(bool (&themap)[S][S]) {
  for( bool(&row)[S]: themap ) {
    bool is_degree_odd = false;
    for( auto col: row )
      is_degree_odd ^= col;
    if( is_degree_odd )
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;

  bool array1[6][6] = {
    {false,true,true,false,false,false},
    {true,false,false,true,false,false},
    {true,false,false,true,false,false},
    {false,true,true,false,true,true},
    {false,false,false,true,false,true},
    {false,false,false,true,true,false}
  };
  cout << "Array 1 has an "
    << (findEvenDegrees(array1) ? "even degree for every" : "odd degree for at least one")
    << " switch." << endl;

  bool array2[8][8]= {
    {false,true,true,false,false,false,false,false},
    {true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false},
    {true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false},
    {false,true,true,false,true,false,false,false},
    {false,false,false,true,false,true,true,false},
    {false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true},
    {false,false,false,false,true,false,false,true},
    {false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false}
  };
  cout << "Array 2 has an "
    << (findEvenDegrees(array2) ? "even degree for every" : "odd degree for at least one")
    << " switch." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In the process of cleaning it up, I eliminated the `if(result%2 == 1) { resultValue = true; break; }`, by effectively returning when I found the first odd-degree row. As I eliminated the `resultValue` variable, I also killed the "unitialized" bug mentioned by @sth.